# MudBlazor editform not taking any values?

Tags: c#, mongodb, blazor, mudblazor

I am creating a project for school and I am at the moment trying to learn how to store values inputted by the user from Blazor Server, into a MongoDb database. In my solution I have of course the Blazor Server app and the API. I have managed to successfully connect the API to the database, testing the connection through Swagger, but Im still having issues when communicating from the Blazor Server to the API.

This is my EditForm:

```
EditForm Model="@guest" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="7">
            <MudCard>
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudTextField Label="First name" Class="mt-3"
                                  @bind-Value="guest.FirstName" For="@(() => guest.FirstName)" />
                    <MudTextField Label="Last name" Class="mt-3"
                                  @bind-Value="guest.LastName" For="@(() => guest.LastName)" />
                    <MudTextField Label="Email" Class="mt-3"
                                  @bind-Value="guest.Email" For="@(() => guest.Email)" />
                    <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Choose a strong password" Class="mt-3"
                                  @bind-Value="guest.Password" For="@(() => guest.Password)" InputType="InputType.Password" />
                </MudCardContent>
                <MudCardActions>
                    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Register</MudButton>
                </MudCardActions>
            </MudCard>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</EditForm>
```

When I try to submit this in using the "register" button:

```
@code {
    bool success;
    public Guest guest = new Guest();

    public async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Guest info: First name: {guest.FirstName}, Last name: {guest.LastName}");

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Guest object: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(guest)}");
            var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("Guests", guest);
            Console.WriteLine($"Response status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Saved successfully");
                guest = new Guest();
                StateHasChanged();
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Response body: {responseBody}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to save guest: {response.StatusCode}");
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"API Response: {responseBody}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving guest: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error in my terminal output:

Guest info: First name: , Last name:
Guest object: {"FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"Email":null,"Phone":null,"Password":null}
Response status code: BadRequest
Failed to save guest: BadRequest
API Response: {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"errors":{"Email":["The Email field is required."],"Phone":["The Phone field is required."],"LastName":["The LastName field is required."],"Password":["The Password field is required."],"FirstName":["The FirstName field is required."]

Is there a fix for this?

I will provide my model for guest as well:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace HavblikkAPI.Models
{
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Guest
    {
        [BsonElement("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the consoles output 'Console.WriteLine($"Guest object: {JsonSerializer.Serialize(guest)}");' and the request body of the http request?

Comment: Hey @Uerschel thank you for the response! The terminal output from those lines have been copied just above the code from my model. I should let you know I have altered my code slightly in the meantime from having the form attach the values directly to the guest variables to making new form variables which I later attach to the guest variables in the code section. The values are now empty instead of null.

Comment: @Uerschel, I have added a new question on my account which includes the newly updated code and terminal output, if you would like to check that out instead!